# Close app in webview mode when going back in flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

I am using InAppWebView package for showing webview in my app. Once I login in webview page it takes me to homepage.

For every navigation if i go back it is takes me back to previous page. If I am on home page n i press back button i want app to be closed.

I tried this way to do it:

```
WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      if (_canGoBack) {
        _webViewController.goBack();
        return Future.value(false);
      }else{
        print("backkkk");
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      return Future.value(true); 
      }
```

Going back to previous pages in history is working fine. but if there's no page left in history or if its home page, app is not getting closed.